# Count and output specific words are in a database row

Tags: php, mysql

```
 id | username | pass | reply         | date    |
 0  | user1    | MD5  | Access-Accept | date 1  | 
 1  | user2    | MD5  | Access-Reject | date 2  |
 2  | user3    | MD5  | Access-Reject | date 3  | 
 3  | user4    | MD5  | Access-Accept | date 4  |
```

Trying to figure it out how to count and show/output all the
     "Access-Accept" an the "Access-Reject" from the table.

here is where I got stuck, the current script is counting all the rows,

```
 <?php
 // start connection 
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_1';
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 echo "";
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $totalsum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

and the html

```
<?php include 'count-words.php';?>
 <p>Total access: <?=$totalsum?> Total Sessions!</div></p>
```

getting forward with the community help and notice that the script does output exactly what I`m looking to achieve.

```
 mysql> SELECT reply, COUNT(reply) FROM radpostauth GROUP BY reply;
 +---------------+--------------+
 | reply         | COUNT(reply) |
 +---------------+--------------+
 | Access-Accept |          573 |
 | Access-Reject |          233 |
 +---------------+--------------+
 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

since php and sql its not my strong attribute I`ll need some help on outputting the result for both rows, like:

```
 <?=$accept?>  
 <?=$reject?>
```

Comment: What is desired result?  Please show as formatted text, as you did for your sample table

Comment: **WARNING**: MD5 passwords are **extremely weak**. At the absolute least use something like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which in PHP is easily supported with [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: I think you are looking for a `Group By` query, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table_1 GROUP BY \`reply\``

Comment: @Azeame, this will echo 2, since all the rows are having the same 2 data (Access-Accept and Access-Reject). I need to add all the Access-Accept and echo the sum ...

Comment: I know everyone wants to make a fancy join statement to show how great a programmer they are, but let's K.I.S.S. and write two queries one for accepted and one for rejected and you'll have two results ($accepted and $rejected) that are clearly identifiable. 

If you were using composer I'd tell you to check out this package [TightenCo/Collect](https://github.com/tightenco/collect) it has fantastic options for grouping, counting, sorting, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT reply,COUNT(reply) FROM table GROUP by reply
```

Just to explain:

`count(reply)` and `group by` gives you the count of each individual value in the column reply. So Access-Accept and Access-Reject will be counted, given your example, you'd receive:

```
   Reply         Count(Reply)
Access-Accept       2
Access-Reject       2
```

Exactly what you seem to be looking for.

You could also an `AS Reply Count` after `COUNT(reply)` so the output says Reply Count instead of count(reply).

Comment: this will echo 2, basically will output only the type: "Access-Accept"  and "Access-Reject". I`m looking into adding how many times "Access-Accept' appears in all the 'reply' rows

Comment: @Michael: This script will do all the counting. You just need to grab the results.